# c# searching using directory class

Tags: c#, directory

I am writing a software tool which, as part of its main task, must search a directory and its sub directories for a directory with a given name, and save to a string array each file path that terminates with the specified directory name.  For example:

```
                   level_1      level_2      Level_3
RootDirectory ---> folderA ---> folderD ---> FolderF ---> Target
             |            |---> folderE ---> Target
             |            
             |---> folderB ---> Target
             |
             |---> FolderC ---> Target
```

should pump out:

```
string[] = {RootDirectory\folderA\FolderD\folderF\Target,  
    RootDirectory\folderA\folderE\Target, 
    Rootdirectory\folderB\Target, 
    RootDirectory\foderC\Target}
```

Originally I used `getDirectories(myPath, "Target", SearchOption.AllDirectories)` on a directory info object, but there was an issue. For some reason, it would find the target under folders b and c, and also under folderA>folderD>folderF, but would skip FolderE.  Once it found the first occurrence within the sub directory, folderA, it would go on to the next folder at level_1.  I should mention that folderD in my real-case was in fact alphabetically sorted before folderE, as it is in this example

so instead I decided to use an `IEnumerator` and run a where filter to select the files that terminate with the given directory name.  This found them all.  However, i cannot figure out how to do something like `getDirectories().Where(x=>(x.attributes & fileattributes.hidden)==0);` on an `IEnumerator`.

The problem is, I need it to skip hidden SVN directories because it is slowing down the process considerably.

So here is my question:
how can I get a collection of all paths within a sub directory that end in a given directory name, and exclude hidden files form the search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're going to have to write your own implementation.  If you are in .net 4.0, you could use [EnumerateDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratedirectories.aspx)

and do something like this:

```
private IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> EnumerateDirectories(DirectoryInfo dir, string target)
{
    foreach (var di in dir.EnumerateDirectories("*",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
    {
        if ((di.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) != FileAttributes.Hidden)
        {
            if (di.Name.EndsWith(target, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                 yield return di;
                 continue;
            }
            foreach (var subDir in EnumerateDirectories(di, target))
            {
                yield return subDir;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\RootDirectory");
var found = EnumerateDirectories(dir,"target").ToArray();
```

This way, once you either find a "target", or run into a hidden directory, you stop going through sub directories.

Comment: thanks for the response! This worked like a charm and turned out to be much faster!  EDIT: i just found out that this skipped two of the directories....i'm in the process of debugging to figure out why.

Comment: Skipped two of the directories?  ...  1) they are inside of a hidden directory, or 2) they do not end with the target you had sent in  ... i don't see any other reason any sub directories would be skipped  ... maybe you intend to do a search that simply contains the target?

Comment: oh...there is a 3rd possibility, you have nested target directories...in that case, remove the continue  (this code will stop going down a directory tree once it finds a target

Answer (score 1):

I created your folder structure in the root of my `C:\` and came up with the following code using Linqpad.

```
string root = "c:\\folderA";
string target = "Target";   
var d = new DirectoryInfo(root);
var x = d.EnumerateDirectories(target, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
x.ToList() // for each element, it's in the the FullName
```

The only part missing is ignoring the `.svn` folders